# how to merge cells in grid of MVC application .Net also i need to export the grid data to excel

Tags: excel, merge, grid, cell

I am working on a MVC application .NET where i have a requirement like :

1. when i load the data in Grid i should be able to merge the grid cells based on condition.
2. the data loaded in grid should be able to export to excel on button click.

Can anybody help me with this

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please show us what you have tried so far and where you got stuck?

Comment: i have managed to show the data in grid and also the export to excel functionality but the merging of cell row wise is where i am stuck. i am using dxDatagrid